# тире нужно? или нет

Tags: пунктуация

Дарт Вейдер - злодей! Тире нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно. Тире ставится, если оба главных члена выражены существительными в именительном падеже.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ли тире или нет?

Оба варианта возможны. См. параграф 10 ПАС:

> Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа...
>
> Примечание. Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи отражено
> произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом: Моя сестра
> учительница  (ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — ударение и на слове
> сестра, и на слове учительница ).